# Restrict items to those where BillingInformation is empty

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to restrict my items to ONLY items with empty billing information ("").

```
Set items = items.restrict("[BillingInformation]=''  ")
```

I have tried the line above, Is Null, Is Empty, = Empty, and a variety of other quote combinations.

What is the correct syntax?

I am using Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

Set items = items.restrict("@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:contacts:billinginformation" & Chr(34) & "IS NULL"

Filtering Items Using a String Comparison
[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867646%28v=office.15%29.aspx)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867646(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867646%28v=office.15%29.aspx)